# Formal definition of summation.

Tags: summation, notation, definition

So i was googling about the formal definition of summation and couldn't find anything, except for the [wikipedia (formal, i suppose) definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation):

> Summation may be defined recursively as follows:
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> \sum_{i=a}^b g(i) &= 0, \text{for } b<a \\
> \sum_{i=a}^b g(i) &= g(b) + \sum_{i=a}^{b-1} g(i), 
> \;\text{for } b \geq a
> \end{align}
> $$

My problem is: this is valid for all $a$, $b$, $i$, and $g(i)$ or there is some condition behind it that I didn't see?

Comment: It depends how formal you want it. See this for very formal https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/df-sum.html

Comment: Formal definitions for monoid can be viewed at  B.L. van der Waerden, F. Blum, J.R. Schulenberg, Algebra, Volume I, Springer,2003, pages 16-17 or  Serge Lang, Algebra, Springer Science & Business Media, 2012, page 4.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. They're assuming $a,\,b\in\Bbb Z$ and values of $g$ are the kinds of things that can be added (complex numbers, conformable matrices thereof and so on, so it's extremely general). Some of the sums thereby defined will be indeterminate forms, but that just means those ones are undefined. Infinite series, however, also require limits.

Comment: Thanks y'all for the help :)